# Check for a word in a dictionary in C

Tags: c, dictionary, data-structures

I have a project in which I have a file (.dic) with many words with different sizes. And another file (.pal) with some words. For each word of the .pal file, I have to find its position in a list of words with the same number of words, ordered alphabetically from the .dic file.

For example,
in the .dic file:

```
car
banana
dog
flower
tar
```

So the dictionary would be something like:

```
3 letters: [car->dab->dog->tar]
6 letters: [banana->flower]
```

in the .pal file:

```
dog
flower
```

So the output would be:

```
dog in position 3 
flower in position 2
```

My question is: **What is the best data structure to implement this in C, so that it takes the least memory and time?**

I was thinking of having a matrix in which each the first index (index1) corresponds to the number of letters in the word, and the second index (index2) corresponds to the first letter of the word I'm looking for. Each element of that matrix is a list of words with index1 letters and starting in letter index2.

Example:

```
 | A  | B  | C  | .....
_______________

1|list|list|list|
2|list|....|....|
3|...
.
.
```

So "dog" would be in a list inside matrix[3][D].

Problem 1: the matrix will have hole if there aren't words with all different number of letters or different first letters -> too much memory wasted?

Problem 2: to know the position I asked before I would have to sum up the number of elements of each list before the one I'm using.

Example: "dog" position would be

```
number of element in list [3][A]+number of element in list [3][B]+number of element in list [3][C]+"dog" position in the list
```

So when I inserted a word in a list, I would have to update the numbers of elements of the lists in the next matrix elements. -> time consuming?

So what do you think of this method? Do you have better ideas?

Comment: have you considered [trie](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/data-structures/7178/trie-prefix-tree-radix-tree#t=201610221652587151612) with added position of the word as another variable?

Comment: Try not to overkill with complex data types. A hash can do it. The answer of 438..... gives a good approach, though I would use a hash of pointers to linked lists, where each list has two entries, pointer to next element and pointer to a word.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best data structure to implement this in C, so that it takes the least memory and time?

It's difficult to get both `least memory` and `least time`. If you want to keep memory usages as low as possible, you'll need dynamic memory allocation which is expensive when considering `time`.

To get low memory usage, you could go for the following data structure:

```
 #define MAX_WORD_LEN 50
 char** dic[MAX_WORD_LEN];
```

You use it like this:

```
index 0: -----> char*, char*, char*, ...   // Words with length 1
                 |      |      |
                 |      |      ------> string (i.e. char, '\0')
                 |      |
                 |      ------> string (i.e. char, '\0')
                 |
                 ------> string (i.e. char, '\0')

index 1: -----> char*, char*, ...   // Words with length 2
                 |      |
                 |      ------> string (i.e. char, char, '\0')
                 |
                 ------> string (i.e. char, char, '\0')
```

This allows you to store a variable number of words for each length and you don't allocate more memory than needed for each string. It is like a matrix but the benefit is that each row can have different number of columns.

You will however need quite some dynamic memory handling, i.e. `malloc`, `realloc` and `strdup`.

To save some execution time you should grow the "char*, char*, char*, ..." array by some N larger than 1 and set the unused entries to NULL. That will save a lot of `realloc` but you'll need to keep track on the number of allocated elements in each row. That could call for something like:

```
struct x
{
    char** data;
    int number_allocated;
}

#define MAX_WORD_LEN 50
struct x dic[MAX_WORD_LEN];
```

If memory usage is real hot, you can avoid the "char*, char* ..." array and just use one big char array for each word length. Like:

```
index 0: -----> 'a', '\0', 'I', '\0', ...
index 1: -----> 'b', 'e', '\0', 't', 'o', '\0', ....
```

You can do this because all words in a char-array has the same length.

In this case you would have something like:

```
struct x
{
    char* data;
    int bytes_allocated;
    int number_of_words;
}

#define MAX_WORD_LEN 50
struct x dic[MAX_WORD_LEN];
```

Comment: Upvote for the idea of using a hash based on word size; in my opinion excellent and simple approach. Though, I think it would be ok to deal with singly linked lists and heap memory. In fact in The C Programming Language there is a good example and a good exercise very similar to that one. It's surely useful; often one wants it to be the most efficient, but I think more importantly one should make it work properly then efficiently. Your idea is a good approach to start with.

Comment: That was my original plan, but to find a word in there (in worst case scenario) the complexity would be N. That's what worries me... How would you do it with heaps? @Elyasin

Comment: Also why would you use arrays instead of lists @4386427

Comment: @newguy - This proposal is focused on memory usage so I wanted to avoid a linked list which costs an extra pointer for each word. (note: If memory usage is real hot, you can do it without all the char pointer but that is a messy approach). I'm not sure I understand your concerns about search speed. If you sort the strings you can use a binary-search approach.